# Best way to parse URL for specific argument?

Tags: regex, url, query-string

I'm trying to parse a huge number of URLs for 3 specific arguments. The URLs themselves are very long and may contain many arguments - I don't need most of them. The arguments come in two ways. Say the name of the argument is `source`, there may be:

- Slash: `/source/stackoverflow/...`
- Query: `?source=stackoverflow&...` (or `&source=...`)

So essentially I want to find `/source/`, `?source=` or `&source=`. I do **not** really care about whether the URL is valid, as long as the part that contains the arguments I want are.

What is the fastest way to achieve this? I've tried regex but it doesn't seem to be fast. If I do brute-force string matching (which is interestingly much faster than regex), what's the best way to do so? I'm trying to find `source=` first and then if not found I look for `/source/`. But that is not as fast as what I hoped either.

My regex is `(?:[\?/&])(?:source)(?:[=/]|(?:%3D))([a-z]+)`, in case it may be helpful.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Have you just tried regex only?

Comment: @hwnd I tried regex and string matching. Neither is fast enough..

Comment: Is it hanging or can you define slow?